# Is the expectation of a random process $X(t)$ with zero DC component necessarily zero?

Tags: autocorrelation, random-process

Is the expectation of a random process $X(t)$ with zero DC component necessarily zero? Or can it be non-zero depending upon the process?

Comment: no, the pdf of amplitudes is symmetric around zero. another way of looking at it is the AC electrical power socket produces power but has a mean voltage of zero

Comment: What is the DC component of a random process? How is it _defined_?

Comment: $X(t)$ is said to have a DC component of $A$ if $X(t) = Y(t) + A$ , where $Y(t)$ has zero DC component.

Comment: That just begs the question since you still haven’t told us what it means for a process to have a zero DC component.

Comment: My guess is the OP is assuming a random process to be DC free iff its power spectral density is zero at $\omega = 0$. But that's just guessing really. So far we don't even know if the process is assumed to be stationary?